# Cannot remove Nexus 5 Network from network list

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

When I click on the Network Manager indicator I have an odd entry in there called Nexus 5 network

[image]

Clicking on it does nothing and it does not show up in the list of networks in Edit Connections

[image]

The university I'm studying at suggests that this is causing some of the connection troubles that I'm having. Can anyone suggest why this is appearing and how I can have it safely removed? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS 13 laptop.

Comment: `gnome-control-center network` showing nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Nexus 5 plugged in with tethering turned on? Ubuntu is seeing it as another network device. There are two obvious remedies here:

- Unplug it
- Turn off tethering

But it's probably not responsible for your wider networking issues.

Comment: I have used it for tethering in the past but I haven't done so for some months yet it's still showing up